# How can I see the value of an alias in a haversine calculation in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following partial code:

```
$query =  "SELECT $table.*, outcodepostcodes.lat, outcodepostcodes.lng
,111.045* DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(". $latpoint ."))
         * COS(RADIANS(outcodepostcodes.lat))
         * COS(RADIANS(". $longpoint .") - RADIANS(outcodepostcodes.lng))
        + SIN(RADIANS(". $latpoint ."))
         * SIN(RADIANS(outcodepostcodes.lat)))) AS distance_in_km
FROM $table     
LEFT JOIN outcodepostcodes
ON UPPER($table.postcode)=outcodepostcodes.outcode
WHERE
$where_no_and
AND 
(hide='0' OR hide IS NULL OR hide='')
HAVING distance_in_km  <= 20
ORDER BY rent $reihenach LIMIT $offset, $rowsPerPage
";
```

How can I is see the value of distance_in_km?

I ran the query and obtained the results using:

```
$num=mysql_numrows($result);
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) 
{
$id=mysql_result($result,$i,"id");
etc
etc
$distance_in_km=mysql_result($result,$i,"distance_in_km");
}
```

but I get this warning:
    Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: distance_in_km not found in MySQL result index 6 in /home/properf/public_html/4Tsalepf.php on line 668

I have added the rest of the code.

Comment: You have to connect to the db, run the query, fetch the results and display the data. What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: I have added the rest of the code and displayed the warning when I try to retrieve the alias 'distance_in_km'.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Comment: @tadman, thanks. I have escaped the quotes within the quotes now. I am returning to programming after a 3 year absence and am aware that much has changed. I have a few technical objectives to achieve (this topic relating to one of them) and will then return to security issues and PDO/mysqli, etc. If anyone can help me with this particular problem it will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved at least one of the problems, which was the Warning:

Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: distance_in_km not found  in MySQL result index 6 in /home/properf/public_html/4Tsalepf.php on line 668

I did this by changing the name of the alias from distance_in_km to simply distance. Apparently, this is something to do with 'identifier quoting'. I have not tried it but probably distance_in_km would also work if I enclosed it in quotes.

However, my problem with being able to access the value of the alias still remains.I first tried  using a subquery, putting the alias in the main query, like so:

```
SELECT distance FROM (
SELECT $table.*, outcodepostcodes.lat, outcodepostcodes.lng
,2*3 AS distance
FROM $table
LEFT JOIN outcodepostcodes
```

and then also replaced the haversine calculation by the simple 2*3 AS distance to try to force the appearance of this result in

$distance = mysql_result($result, $i, "distance");

However, when I echo $distance it is still empty, not the expected 6 (ie 2*3).

Any ideas greatly appreciated.Thanks.